# Can a person's body produce enough electricity to break a wristwatch?

Tags: energy

I know of someone who cannot seem to wear watches without the battery dying or something else about the watch going haywire. this person was told it is because their body is producing too much electricity and that by putting nail polish on the reverse of the watch to block the current the watch would work.
This was tried and it actually worked. My question is, is this a real thing? I couldn't find a legit discussion of this online.

Comment: Static electricity (depending on clothes, floor material, air humidity, etc...) seems more plausible.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that sweat or something similar would be more likely. (That is a guess, though.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is better suited to skeptics SE - I don't view this as a biology question

Comment: I do think this has the potential (haha, electricity joke) to be a very interesting question - there's a lot of anecdotal evidence out there about people (a friend of mine included) who cannot wear watches because they are continually dying or otherwise malfunctioning. It would be great if someone could find a study on this.